# Python, Regex everything before a sequence

Tags: python, regex, dataframe

I have a data frame column which contains the following strings.
I want to parse everything to the left of the 4 or 5 digit number into a separate column

```
column name
    0   129 4,029.16 08-31-13 8043 304.12 02-28-13 00T773466
    1   19 179.00 03-31-12 T0707440 7794 2,898.56 01-31-13 00T757276
    2   19716 3.36 01-31-15 00T729912 30593 6,041.74 12-31-16 00T770362
    3   19870 131.22 02-28-15 00T709284 4 30611 199.46 02-03-23 12-31-16 00T691818
    4   19984 12.25 02-28-15 00T879664 30647 199.45 12-31-16 00T691818
    5   20505 1,206.13 03-31-15 00T590582 30648 199.45 12-31-16 00T691818
    6   20623 84.11 04-30-15 00T621725 30759 3,325.27 12-31-16 00T580639
```

So the desired dataframe column would look something like this:

```
before
0   129 4,029.16 08-31-13
1   19 179.00 03-31-12 T0707440
2   19716 3.36 01-31-15 00T729912
3   19870 131.22 02-28-15 00T709284 4
4   19984 12.25 02-28-15 00T879664
5   20505 1,206.13 03-31-15 00T590582
6   20623 84.11 04-30-15 00T621725
```

I tried parsing everything to the right of the 4 or 5 digit using

```
df['after']=df['column_name'].str.extract('(\s\d{4,5}\s+.*)')
```

And it works but how do I do the same to obtain df['before']?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You're a step away from the expected output, you just need a *lookahead* :

```
df["before"] = df["column_name"].str.extract(r"(.*)\s(?=\b\d{4,5}\b)")
```

​
Output :

```
print(df["before"])

0                129 4,029.16 08-31-13
1          19 179.00 03-31-12 T0707440
2        19716 3.36 01-31-15 00T729912
3    19870 131.22 02-28-15 00T709284 4
4       19984 12.25 02-28-15 00T879664
5    20505 1,206.13 03-31-15 00T590582
6       20623 84.11 04-30-15 00T621725
Name: after, dtype: object
```

If you need both (`before/after`), you can use :

```
df[["before", "after"]] = df["column_name"].str.extract(r"(.*)\s+\b\d{4,5}\b\s+(.*)")
```

Output :

```
                              before                               after
0              129 4,029.16 08-31-13           304.12 02-28-13 00T773466
1        19 179.00 03-31-12 T0707440         2,898.56 01-31-13 00T757276
2      19716 3.36 01-31-15 00T729912         6,041.74 12-31-16 00T770362
3  19870 131.22 02-28-15 00T709284 4  199.46 02-03-23 12-31-16 00T691818
4     19984 12.25 02-28-15 00T879664           199.45 12-31-16 00T691818
5  20505 1,206.13 03-31-15 00T590582           199.45 12-31-16 00T691818
6     20623 84.11 04-30-15 00T621725         3,325.27 12-31-16 00T580639
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative, using `.str.replace`:

```py
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].str.replace(r'(?<=.{15})\s+\d{4,5}\s+.*', '', regex=True)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                         column_name
0              129 4,029.16 08-31-13
1        19 179.00 03-31-12 T0707440
2      19716 3.36 01-31-15 00T729912
3  19870 131.22 02-28-15 00T709284 4
4     19984 12.25 02-28-15 00T879664
5  20505 1,206.13 03-31-15 00T590582
6     20623 84.11 04-30-15 00T621725
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to match before the first occurrence of `\s\d{4,5}\s` you can use a capture group with a non greedy quantifier:

```
df['after'] = df['column_name'].str.extract('^(.*?)\s\d{4,5}\s')
print(df)
```

Output

```
                                         column_name                              after
0  129 4,029.16 08-31-13 8043 304.12 02-28-13 00T...              129 4,029.16 08-31-13
1  19 179.00 03-31-12 T0707440 7794 2,898.56 01-3...        19 179.00 03-31-12 T0707440
2  19716 3.36 01-31-15 00T729912 30593 6,041.74 1...      19716 3.36 01-31-15 00T729912
3  19870 131.22 02-28-15 00T709284 4 30611 199.46...  19870 131.22 02-28-15 00T709284 4
4  19984 12.25 02-28-15 00T879664 30647 199.45 12...     19984 12.25 02-28-15 00T879664
5  20505 1,206.13 03-31-15 00T590582 30648 199.45...  20505 1,206.13 03-31-15 00T590582
6  20623 84.11 04-30-15 00T621725 30759 3,325.27 ...     20623 84.11 04-30-15 00T621725
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want both the text before and after the 4/5 digit number, you can [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) on that number:

```py
df[['before','after']] = df['column name'].str.split(r'\s+\d{4,5}\s+',expand=True)
```

Output (`before` and `after`):

```
                              before                               after
0              129 4,029.16 08-31-13           304.12 02-28-13 00T773466
1        19 179.00 03-31-12 T0707440         2,898.56 01-31-13 00T757276
2      19716 3.36 01-31-15 00T729912         6,041.74 12-31-16 00T770362
3  19870 131.22 02-28-15 00T709284 4  199.46 02-03-23 12-31-16 00T691818
4     19984 12.25 02-28-15 00T879664           199.45 12-31-16 00T691818
5  20505 1,206.13 03-31-15 00T590582           199.45 12-31-16 00T691818
6     20623 84.11 04-30-15 00T621725         3,325.27 12-31-16 00T580639
```

You can also use a capture group to save the number as well:

```py
df[['before','num','after']] = df['column name'].str.split(r'\s+(\d{4,5})\s+',expand=True)
```

Output (`before`, `num` and `after`):

```
                              before    num                               after
0              129 4,029.16 08-31-13   8043           304.12 02-28-13 00T773466
1        19 179.00 03-31-12 T0707440   7794         2,898.56 01-31-13 00T757276
2      19716 3.36 01-31-15 00T729912  30593         6,041.74 12-31-16 00T770362
3  19870 131.22 02-28-15 00T709284 4  30611  199.46 02-03-23 12-31-16 00T691818
4     19984 12.25 02-28-15 00T879664  30647           199.45 12-31-16 00T691818
5  20505 1,206.13 03-31-15 00T590582  30648           199.45 12-31-16 00T691818
6     20623 84.11 04-30-15 00T621725  30759         3,325.27 12-31-16 00T580639
```